# Comparable<Integer> array comparison java

Tags: java, conditional-statements, mergesort, comparable

I'm tasked with writing mergesort in java, the task also specified I can't use integers, I have to use Comparable integers. This is my first time using java.
My problem is comparing elements in two comp-int arrays inside the merging function.
I have tried `if (list[i].compareTo(list2[j])` but the compareTo can only take integers.
any help would be appreciated

```
public static Comparable<Integer>[] merge(Comparable<Integer> list[], Comparable<Integer> list2[] ) {
        Comparable<Integer> C[];
        int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
        while (i < list.length && j < list2.length) {

            if (list[i] < list2[j]]) {
                C[k] = list[i];
                i++; k++;
            } else {
                C[k] = list2[j];
                j++; k++;
            }
        }
        while (i < list.length) {
            C[k++] = list[i++];
        }
        while (j < list2.length) {
            C[k++] = list2[j++];
        }
        return C;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that `compareTo()` returns an 'int', but `if ()` requires a `boolean` - you can change it to `if (list[i].compareTo(list2[j]) < 0)` - see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: double check that the instructor didn't ask for `Comparator<Integer>`, which might make more sense.

Comment: The normal way to use `Comparable` here would be to make your method take values of a generic `T extends Comparable<T>`. Did the lesson mention anything about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should be doing.

```
public static Integer [] merge(Integer[] list, Integer[]list2 ) {
    Integer[] C = new Integer[list.length + list2.length];
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
    while (i < list.length && j < list2.length) {

        if (list[i].compareTo(list2[j]) < 0) {
            C[k] = list[i];
            i++; k++;
        } else {
            C[k] = list2[j];
            j++; k++;
        }
    }
    while (i < list.length) {
        C[k++] = list[i++];
    }
    while (j < list2.length) {
        C[k++] = list2[j++];
    }
    return C;
}
```

You are supposed to use `Comparable<Integer>` to test the array elements (as opposed to the common, `<, == , and >` operators).  Since the `Integer` class implements the `Comparable<T>` interface you can probably fulfill your assignment by doing the following:

`list[i].compareTo(list2[j] < 0)` and not `list[i] < list2[j]`

Nothing else makes sense.  Especially passing two arrays of `Comparable<Integer>` which has already been pointed out. If this is not your understanding then you should discuss with your instructor.

Comment: There should be a name for this. "Homework archeology"? Trying to figure out what the assignment's text wants you to do. I concur - this sounds quite plausible.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yeah.  I don't like to give answers unless I know what the OP really wants.  But then, sometimes, comments simply aren't enough to sufficiently obtain the desired information.

Answer (score 2):

Just `Integer` is what you want. It *is* `Comparable<Integer>` (try it: `Comparable<Integer> i = Integer.valueOf(10);` works fine!) - a `Comparable<Integer>` can compare 2 Integer instances. It cannot compare 2 `Comparable<Integer>` instances.

Every place in your code where you wrote `Comparable<Integer>` should just be `Integer`.

Comment: I know, the problem is the assignment prohibits using Integer, The edX course instructor wants Comparable<integer> and I can't figure out a way to convert

Comment: Hm, weird. Only 2 things I can think of: You misunderstood the assignment (the edX course instructor meant something different), or the edX course instructor misunderstands java. If truly the task is exactly as you interpreted it, it's.. useless. It cannot fathom what this should teach you, and it doesn't look like any real life code you'd ever write. Or perhaps they are trying to make some sort of point I can't see here.

Comment: I think @WJS's answer is taking a plausible guess: Specifically, you misunderstood it, the point your instructor was attempting to make is that you should be using `a.compareTo(b)`, as in, use the fact that `Integer` is also a `Comparable<Integer>`, and not `a < b`. I can see how one would somewhat haphandedly say "use `Comparable<Integer>` for this assignment" to convey that wish.